# Sync Issues with Google Calendar and WooCommerce Bookings

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, google-calendar-api

I am having an issue whereby not all my bookings are showing in the Google Calendar. Having looked at the log files I get the following message. The project referred to was created automatically by the api so I cannot check itys settings and it is not listed in my Google Console.

```
2020-08-01T06:45:43+00:00 NOTICE Error while getting event for Booking 54038: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Quota exceeded for quota group 'default' and limit 'Queries per day' of service 'calendar-json.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:221931625241'.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Quota exceeded for quota group 'default' and limit 'Queries per day' of service 'calendar-json.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:221931625241'.",
        "domain": "usageLimits",
        "reason": "rateLimitExceeded"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

any ideas how to solve please?

Comment: What do you mean by "The project was created by the API"? What credentials are you using if the project was created by the API? Also the reach of quotas is a thing that you cannot fight? Do you have information about how many requests are you sending?

Answer (score 0):

I contacted WooCommerce about this very same issue. It seems like WooCommerce's Bookings 'app' uses a single API key for !!!every!!! WooCommerce Bookings installation.

Here's a chat with WooCommerce that I had a while back (3 June 2020).

[Image of conversation with WooCommerce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqEKo.png)